# Read from kafka 0.9.0 and write to kafka 3.1.0 in Storm ETL projects

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am working on an Apache Storm ETL project which needs to read from Kafka 0.9.0 and write to the version 3.1.0. Do you know how the Kafka-3 info should be provided?

I created a bolt class which its constructor has two arguments topic name and bootsrtaps info.

public class CPPKafkaBolt<K, V> extends BaseRichBolt {
private static final long                     serialVersionUID        = -5205886631877033478L;

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaBolt.class);

public static final String TOPIC = "topic";

private Producer<String, String> producer;
private OutputCollector collector;
private TupleToKafkaMapper<K,V> mapper;
private KafkaTopicSelector topicSelector;
private Properties boltSpecfiedProperties = new Properties();
/**
 * With default setting for fireAndForget and async, the callback is called when the sending succeeds.
 * By setting fireAndForget true, the send will not wait at all for kafka to ack.
 * "acks" setting in 0.8.2 Producer API config doesn't matter if fireAndForget is set.
 * By setting async false, synchronous sending is used.
 */
private boolean fireAndForget = false;
private boolean async = true;

private String bootstrapServers;

public CPPKafkaBolt(String bootstrapServers, String topic) {
    this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
    this.topicSelector = (new DefaultTopicSelector(topic));
}

public CPPKafkaBolt<K,V> withTupleToKafkaMapper(TupleToKafkaMapper<K,V> mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
    return this;
}

public CPPKafkaBolt<K,V> withTopicSelector(KafkaTopicSelector selector) {
    this.topicSelector = selector;
    return this;
}

public CPPKafkaBolt<K,V> withProducerProperties(Properties producerProperties) {
    this.boltSpecfiedProperties = producerProperties;
    return this;
}

@Override
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    //for backward compatibility.
    if(mapper == null) {
        this.mapper = new FieldNameBasedTupleToKafkaMapper<K,V>();
    }

    //for backward compatibility.
    if(topicSelector == null) {
        this.topicSelector = new DefaultTopicSelector((String) stormConf.get(TOPIC));
    }

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.bootstrapServers);
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer1 = new KafkaProducer<>(
            props, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());
    this.producer = producer1;

    this.mapper = new FieldNameBasedTupleToKafkaMapper();
    this.collector = collector;
}

@Override
public void execute(final Tuple input) {
    if (TupleUtils.isTick(input)) {
        collector.ack(input);
        return; // Do not try to send ticks to Kafka
    }

    K key;
    V message;
    String topic;
    try {
        key = mapper.getKeyFromTuple(input);
        message = mapper.getMessageFromTuple(input);
        topic = topicSelector.getTopic(input);
        if (topic != null ) {
            Callback callback = null;

            if (!fireAndForget && async) {
                callback = new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata ignored, Exception e) {
                        synchronized (collector) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                collector.reportError(e);
                                collector.fail(input);
                            } else {
                                collector.ack(input);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            Future<RecordMetadata> result = producer.send(new ProducerRecord("topic", "key", "message"), (Callback)callback);
            if (!async) {
                try {
                    result.get();
                    collector.ack(input);
                } catch (ExecutionException err) {
                    collector.reportError(err);
                    collector.fail(input);
                }
            } else if (fireAndForget) {
                collector.ack(input);
            }
        } else {
            LOG.warn("skipping key = " + key + ", topic selector returned null.");
            collector.ack(input);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        collector.reportError(ex);
        collector.fail(input);
    }
}

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {

}

@Override
public void cleanup() {
    producer.close();
}

public void setFireAndForget(boolean fireAndForget) {
    this.fireAndForget = fireAndForget;
}

public void setAsync(boolean async) {
    this.async = async;
}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem? There's no client property difference between those versions. You'll need a KafkaSink to write anywhere

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).